# Adobe AEM Querybuilder Debugger - Multiple Paths and Multiple Nodenames

Tags: adobe, aem

I am using querybuilder debugger and want to do a search where "nodename=*.pdf OR nodename=*.doc*" and "path=/content/dam/1 OR path=/content/dam/2".

I have been trying to find an example but no luck on the web. What I have below is not quite right - just wondering what I am missing.

The query does work but there is a huge difference in the amount of time that it runs when compared with when I just query using one nodename instead of 2.

Thanks in advance,

Jerry

```
type=dam:asset
mainasset=true
1_group.p.or=true
1_group.1.nodename=*.pdf
1_group.2.nodename=*.doc*
2_group.p.or=true
2_group.1_path=/content/dam/1
2_group.2_path=/content/dam/2
p.limit=-1
orderby=path
```

I thought maybe something as simple as this might work but no luck....

```
type=dam:asset
mainasset=true
group.p.or=true
group.1_nodename=*.doc*
group.1_path=/content/dam/1
group.2_nodename=*.doc*
group.2_path=/content/dam/2
group.3_nodename=*.pdf
group.3_path=/content/dam/1
group.4_nodename=*.pdf
group.4_path=/content/dam/2
p.limit=-1
orderby=path
```

Comment: Did you try with SQL2 syntax as well?

Comment: Hi ronnyfm,

No, just the code that I posted. Our programmer said that when we update to AEM 6.5 (we are currently using AEM 6.2), the advanced query will run much faster (he tried it in  a test environment) - no idea why though.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting your query if this won't affect the behaviour you're trying to achieve.

```
path=/content/dam/1
type=dam:asset
mainasset=true
group.1.nodename=*.pdf
group.2.nodename=*.doc*
p.limit=-1
orderby=path
```

```
path=/content/dam/2
type=dam:asset
mainasset=true
group.1.nodename=*.pdf
group.2.nodename=*.doc*
p.limit=-1
orderby=path
```

Comment: Hi Yahya - thank you for responding. I am more familiar with SQL and DB queries.....maybe not possible to do something like "where type=dam:asset AND (path=/content/dam/1 OR path=/content/dam/2) AND (nodename=*.doc OR nodename=*.pdf), orderby=path"?

Comment: Hi Jerryle, i guess that what you already did with your first query, maybe there is something else that making the request so slow not that the query on its own ...